# How can I give a list_string BaseFieldDefinition in a content entity a default starting value?

Tags: 8, entities

I have an entity with a list_string field in my content entity that outputs to the entity form as a list of checkboxes. IE:

```
$fields['colors'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create("list_string")
  ->setSettings([
    'allowed_values' => ['blue' => 'Blue', 'red' => 'Red', 'green' => 'Green']
  ])
  ->setLabel('Color')
  ->setDescription('Select color')
  ->setRequired(TRUE)
  ->setCardinality(-1)
  ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
    'type' => 'options_buttons',
    'weight' => 2,
  ))
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE);
```

Is there a way for me to give this field a default *starting* value. IE, when the user creates a new entity, red and green start out selected on the form?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use setDefaultValue method:

```
BaseFieldDefinition::setDefaultValue([['value' => 'red'], ['value' => 'green']])
```

That will also work for entities not created in the UI.

Comment: Where can we see the documentation of all the setSettings options / methods for list_string BaseFieldDefinition?

Answer (score 2):

From https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/content_entity_example%21src%21Entity%21Contact.php/function/Contact%3A%3AbaseFieldDefinitions/8.x-1.x

```
// Role field for the contact.
  // The values shown in options are 'administrator' and 'user'.
  $fields['role'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('list_string')
    ->setLabel(t('Role'))
    ->setDescription(t('The role of the Contact entity.'))
    ->setSettings([
    'allowed_values' => [
      'administrator' => 'administrator',
      'user' => 'user',
    ],
  ])
    ->setDefaultValue('user')
    ->setDisplayOptions('view', [
    'label' => 'above',
    'type' => 'string',
    'weight' => -2,
  ])
    ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
    'type' => 'options_select',
    'weight' => -2,
  ])
    ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
    ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that adding this to the entity form file did the trick:

```
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    /* @var $entity \Drupal\mymodule\Entity\MyEntity */
    $form = parent::buildForm($form, $form_state);
    $entity = $this->entity;

    if($entity->isNew())
    {
      $form['colors']['widget']['#default_value'] = ['red', 'green'];
    }
```